# Corollary of Fubini's Theorem: the product of integrals is the integral of the product

Tags: integration, measure-theory, riemann-integration

Consider the function
$$
f(x,y)=h(x)\times g(y)
$$
By Fubini's Theorem
$$
\int_{X}h(x)dx \times \int_{Y}g(y)dy= \int_{X\times Y}h(x)g(y)d(x,y)
$$

Questions:

(1) Is this correct?

(2) Can be extended to the product of any number of functions?

(3) Are there particular conditions to check other than measurability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that the product of the integrals equals the integral of the products. And yes, this can be extended to triple products, and quadruple products, and so on.

In general, Fubini's theorem only holds when $f(x,y)$ is *integrable*, i.e. when $\int_{X \times Y} |f(x,y)| d(x,y) < \infty.$ But in your situation, $f(x,y)$ is a product of $h(x)$ and $g(y)$, which are integrable *by assumption*. Hence the product $f(x,y)=h(x)g(y)$ is guaranteed to be integrable and everything works okay.

Comment: Hang on, you're dealing with products of functions, aren't you? That actually makes things simpler. Hold on...

Comment: Could I ask you whether the Fubini's statement can be written also as $\int_{X}h(x)dx\times \int_{Y}g(y)dy=\int_X\int_Y h(x)g(y)dx dy$? Or this is just an identity?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The expression $\int_X \int_Y h(x)g(y)dxdy$ is shorthand for $\int_X \left( \int_Y h(x)g(y) dy \right) dx$. But from the point of view of the $y$-integral, the $h(x)$ factor is a constant, so the $h(x)$ factor can be taken outside the $y$-integral, leaving you with $\int_X \left( \int_Y g(y) dy \right)h(x) dx$. But then, from the point of view of the $x$-integral, the factor of $\left( \int_Y g(y) dy \right)$ is a constant, so it can be taken outside the $x$-integral, giving the expression $\int_X h(x) dx \times \int_Y g(y) dy$.

Comment: So to clarify, the thing you wrote 9 minutes ago is not a consequence of Fubini. It is true by the very definition of  the thing on the right-hand side of your equation. Fubini tells you that the left- and right-hand sides of the thing you wrote 9 minutes ago is equal to the integral w.r.t. the product measure, $\int_{X \times Y} h(x)g(y) d(x,y)$.