# Proof that any two random variables are independent

Tags: calculus, probability

Let X and Y be two continuous random variables with densities $p_X(x)$ and $p_Y(y)$, respectively.

By normalization, $\int p_X(x)dx = 1$. Viewed as a marginal distribution, we can express  $p_X(x)$ as $\int p_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$. Substituting back into the normalization condition and applying Fubini's theorem to switch the order of integration gives us $$\iint p_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy = 1$$

Alternatively, consider the product $(\int p_X(x)dx)(\int p_Y(y)dy) = 1$. A [corollary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177692/corollary-of-fubinis-theorem-the-product-of-integrals-is-the-integral-of-the-p) to Fubini's theorem lets us treat this product of integrals as an integral of the product of integrands: $$\iint p_X(x)p_Y(y)dxdy = 1$$

What's wrong with this reasoning? Clearly the joint distribution does not generally equal the product of the marginals without the assumption of independence (which is absent here).

Comment: Edited to use $p_X(x)$ instead of $p(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what you think the problem is.  You have found that $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and $p_X(x)p_Y(y)$ give the same result when integrated.  That doesn't mean they are the same function!  Indeed, *any* density function at all has an integral of $1$; that doesn't mean all distributions are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially established that $1\cdot1=1$, which is a known result.

It does not imply at all that $p(x,y)=p'(x)\cdot p''(y)$.