# How does one explain this inequality which swaps integral and product?

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, integral-inequality

I'm reading a proof which ends with:

$$ \ldots= \int_A  \prod_{i\in D}p_\psi(y_i) d y_1 \cdots d y_n \leq \prod_{i\in D} \left[ \int p_\psi(y_i) d y_i \right] = 1 $$

I didn't follow the inequality where the product can be pulled outside the integral. Here $D$ is dataset, $\psi$ are the parameters of a probability distribution, $y_i$ is the $i$th iid observations of the unknown distribution in the dataset.

At first, I thought this might be an application of Cauchy-Schwarz but it seems like that introduces a squared term that I wouldn't know how to get rid of (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz_Inequality/Definite_Integrals).

Any explanation much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Is this related? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177692/corollary-of-fubinis-theorem-the-product-of-integrals-is-the-integral-of-the-p

Comment: If $A$ being on the left but not the right is significant, then perhaps you have $ \int_A  \prod_{i\in D}p_\psi(y_i) d y_1 \cdots d y_n \leq \int  \prod_{i\in D}p_\psi(y_i) d y_1 \cdots d y_n = \prod_{i\in D} \left[ \int p_\psi(y_i) d y_i \right]$

Comment: This seems to be Fubini's theorem + the estimate mentioned by @Henry.