# Why do I need Fubini to evaluate these integrals of products of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I am currently reading a book on applied mathematics, and the current chapter is proving some statements related to probability theory. I'm stuck with one step in a derivation, because the author claims to use Fubini('s theorem), but I do not see why he would need it.

Concretely, consider continuous random variables $X, Y$ on $\mathcal{X}$ with probability densities $p(x), q(y)$, respectively, as well as a function $\phi:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^N$. The steps in question are $$\mathbb{E}_p[\phi(X)^T]\mathbb{E}_p[\phi(X)]=\int\phi(x)^Tp(x)dx\int\phi(x')p(x')dx'=\int\int\phi(x)^T\phi(x')p(x)p(x')dxdx'$$ and
$$\mathbb{E}_p[\phi(X)^T]\mathbb{E}_q[\phi(Y)]=\int\phi(x)^Tp(x)dx\int\phi(y)q(y)dy=\int\phi(x)^T\phi(y)p(x)q(y)dxdy$$
I can not figure out why there would be any need to use Fubini in either step. What's more, I think that the order of integration wouldn't matter either way, since according to my understanding I can just do (e.g. in the second case):
$$\int\phi(x)^Tp(x)dx\int\phi(y)q(y)dy=\int\left(\int\phi(y)q(y)dy\right)\phi(x)^Tp(x)dx=\int\left(\int\phi(y)q(y)\phi(x)^Tp(x)dy\right)dx$$ where in the first step I used that the integral in parentheses exists and hence has a constant value, and in the second step that $\phi(x)^Tp(x)$ is constant with respect to $y$. Analogously, $$\int\phi(x)^Tp(x)dx\int\phi(y)q(y)dy=\int\left(\int\phi(x)^Tp(x)dx\right)\phi(y)q(y)dy=\int\left(\int\phi(y)q(y)\phi(x)^Tp(x)dx\right)dy$$
Which means the order of integration does not matter. (I understand that this would be different if the integrand were e.g. a function $h(x,y)$ for which I wouldn't just have $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ for some appropriate $f,g$, and then I would need Fubini.

Does anybody see why the author would write that one needs Fubini?

Answer (score 2):

An important fact about integrals that is sometimes glossed over in calculus courses is that, in general, an iterated integral is not the same thing as an integral over a product domain. Fubini's theorem gives us conditions under which they *are* equal. Changing the order of integration is really just a byproduct of this subtler idea.

You are actually applying Fubini in your argument for why it's unnecessary. This may be a little clearer if we work in the other direction, that is, start with the integral over the product domain and move to the product of integrals.

Let $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$, where $g$ and $h$ are integrable on the domains $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ respectively, and $\iint_{\Omega_1\times \Omega_2} |f(x,y)| dA <\infty$. Then by Fubini we have the following:

\begin{align}
\iint_{\Omega_1\times \Omega_2} f(x,y) dA  &= \iint_{\Omega_1\times \Omega_2} g(x)h(y) dA \\
  &=  \int_{\Omega_2} \left[ \int_{\Omega_1} g(x) dx \right] h(y)dy
\end{align}

We need Fubini here because the integral over the product $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ is not in general the same as an iterated integral over $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ separately. Both results you've asked about are just using Fubini to justify that the double integral equals the iterated integral.

Comment: No. I know that the iterated integral is (in general) not the same thing as the integral over the product domain, and I understand that Fubini describes conditions under which they are equal. My claim is that the author is **not** considering the product domain, resp. doesn't have to, which is what I wanted to express with my two derivations showing that $\int\left(\int\phi(y)q(y)\phi(x)^Tp(x)dy\right)dx=\int\left(\int\phi(y)q(y)\phi(x)^Tp(x)dx\right)dy$. The parentheses mean iterated integration, and in particular no product measure is used.

Comment: I read the author's $\int\int\phi(x)^T\phi(y)p(x)q(y)dxdy$ as $\int\left(\int\phi(x)^T\phi(y)p(x)q(y)dx\right)dy$ (otherwise he should write $d(x,y)$ instead of $dxdy$. **My overall claim/suspicion is that in the case $h(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ the order of integration does not matter even without utilizing Fubini**. Cf. also the comments under the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177692/corollary-of-fubinis-theorem-the-product-of-integrals-is-the-integral-of-the-p, which I think mean what I am suspecting but am not sure.

Comment: Authors aren't always super precise when it comes to notating something like $dxdy$ vs. $d(x,y)$. Without seeing the notation throughout the rest of the book or the rest of the derivation, I can't really say if I agree that the author isn't considering the product domain. The mention of Fubini suggests they are and maybe just not being explicit about it. But yes, in this case the two iterated integrals are the same without fubini, we just can't say they are the same as the double integral.